# Calculating average in panda depending on a name of a other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns like this.

```
   name     length
0   Pk      78
2   Pk      59
4   Pk      283
6   Ser     100
7   Ig_2    79
8   Ig_2    77
9   Ser     369
```

I want to calculate the average of each name.
    For example

```
Pk - 140
ser -234.5
Ig_2 -78
```

How can i do this with python panda.

I was trying this.

```
df.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

but didn't work.
Is there anyway to use rolling() function for this?

Comment: What do you mean by name? Please format your data properly.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Sorry, it was a mistake. I have formatted the data

Comment: `df.groupby('name').mean()`

Comment: Also what does _didn’t work_ mean, exactly? Did you look at the docs to see what the `level` parameter does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['pk', 78], ['pk', 59], ['Ig', 79], ['Ig', 77]], colu
   ...: mns=['name', 'length'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  name  length
0   pk      78
1   pk      59
2   Ig      79
3   Ig      77

In [4]: df.groupby('name').mean()
Out[4]:
      length
name
Ig      78.0
pk      68.5
```

To sort values in ascending order:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('name').mean().sort_values(by='length', 
ascending=True)
Out[11]:
      length
name
pk      68.5
Ig      78.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me how can i make it in ascending order. i mean the answer

Comment: `df.groupby('name').mean().sort_values(by='length', 
ascending=True)`